# New issue Chrome opacity 0 not clickable

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Hi i have a new issue with chrome , for some reason i want to click on element (iframe) when the opacity is set to 0 ! It was working some days ago but not anymore on Chrome ? But still working good on safari ! Any alternative to hide an element but still click on it ?

Comment: Do you have some code to go with this?

Comment: My project shows the same behaviour in Chrome. Also tried it in Safari where it works fine. How come so?

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix : put `opacity:0.0000000001` did the trick !

Comment: HAha, that's cheating

Comment: I tried chrome and set `opacity:0` and still can click on the element(I tried button and a )